# What to do in C when there is no valid value to return?

Tags: c, function, declaration

I have an array of elements defined by several parameters and a unique id, I have created a function which returns the element associated with a certain unique id, the thing is that if an invalid ID is entered (one that isn't stored by the array), there is no valid value to return for my function.

My issue is that my code won't compile if the function doesn't necessarily return something, is there a way to tell the compiler that this is ok to do that here ?

Thank you.

Comment: Post some of your code.

Comment: Code example would help...

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways to do this.

The simplest way is to return a value that is not in the valid range of values.

Another way is to declare one more parameter that is a pointer to a variable that serves as an error. Or to return an error value and to return the valid value as a parameter declared like a reference.

For example

```
int /* error */ f( T *valid_value );
```

One more way is to return a structure of two values one of which is a Boolean value that reports a failure or success.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define an invalid value, such value is simply one that does not belong to the set of valid values.

For example:

If valid values are *[0, inf)* then *-1* is a good *invalid value*.

Comment: I'm a bit torn on this approach. Because it sacrifices a huge range of values just to get a single invalid one. I often times try to make `0` the invalid value, and the range all other unsigned integers (of some size).

Comment: @StoryTeller This approach is only valid if the set of valid values is truly limited and well defined. Of course, there are other approaches, but this one is simple and hence elegant. Although, it certainly doesn't work all the time. Also, I believe it's used in many important applications, for instance `'\0'` for string termination and `NULL` for pointers are the most widely used and standardized. I could go on, `EOF` ... but you get the point.

Answer (score 1):

I would return a pointer to the element rather than the element itself. Such as this.

```
struct Element* find(struct Element* elements, int count, int id)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
      if(elements[i].id == id)
         return elements + i; //pointer to i'th element
   }
   return NULL; //if it makes it here return NULL since no element was found.
}
```

Then you can do something like this.

```
struct Element* e = find(elements, m, 1234);
if(e) //check and see if it is not null
{
   //handle found case
}
else
{
   //handle not found case
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with your approach, you can pass `NULL` to `free()` but you can't pass the return value of this function to `free()`. It's almost the same that I suggested, but `NULL` has it's own use cases. Perhaps, an element with invalid members and `int element_is_valid(Element *)` function would do. Also, attaching the `*` to the type is a bad idea and makes me wanna rip my eyes off!

Comment: I'm not convinced that "cannot free the return value" is a valid complaint.

Answer (score 0):

> ..... is there a way to tell the compiler that this is ok to do that here ?

No, there is no way to do that.

A function must always return a value of the same type (i.e. the type you gave in the declaration) or never return anything (i.e. declared as `void foo(...)`).

You can't return a value in some cases and return "nothing" in other case. Likewise, you can't return an integer in some cases and a struct in other cases. The return value must be the same in all cases.

The general work around is to introduce a way to tell the caller that the function failed to find the requested element. There are multiple ways of doing that as mentioned in other answers. Which solution to go for depends on your code and needs.

I usually prefer that the function returns an `int` where the value zero means "failed" and non-zero means "success". I would then "return" the element using a pointer. Like this pseudo code:

```
int foo(struct MyStruct *p, .....)
{
     if (found.....)
     {
          *p = the_found_element;
          return 1;
     }
     return 0; 
 }


 struct MyStruct ms;
 if (foo(&ms, ....))
 {
     // okay - carry on using ms
     ...
 }
 else
 {
     // failure - don't use ms as it is invalid
     ... 
  }
```